# Based on the client id process should allocate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I got the below error when I fetch the process from client_process table

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'client_id'
```

**models.py**

This is my models file the client and client_process are foreign key

```
class Client_files(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    client_process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    File_Name = models.FileField()
    Pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client_files'
```

**views.py**

```
def pdf_upload(request):
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    print(pdf)
    obj = Client_files.objects.values('client_id')
    print(obj)
    for i in range(len(obj)):
        client = Client_Process.objects.filter(client_id__in=obj[i])
        print(client)
        obj[i].client = client

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = Upload_files(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/pdf/upload/')
    else:
        form = Upload_files()
    return render(request,'uploadpdf.html',{'form':form, 'pdf':pdf,})
```

Comment: You have already added the `print(obj)` statement to debug the issue; what do you see? It should tell you the problem.

Comment: No, It filter the client_id from Client_files table

Comment: Look at it carefully. It returns a queryset, not a list.

Comment: Yeah, it return a Queryset, and I pass to Client_Process to filter the process based on the client_id